# Count number of failures from multiple XML test report files

Tags: xml, junit, xml-parsing, xmllint

I have a jenkins job that creates multiple xml test report files.
ecah file contains a entry like
.
Is there a way I can calculate total number of failures from multiple such files

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Using PowerShell with a XML Linq query.  Need to see sample of Xml.